# AzCopy v6.2.0 not copying at all

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azcopy

I am having a release pipeline. In there, I've added one task `Azure CLI`. In there, I chose `2.0` Preview as Task Version. For Script Type, I chose `PowerShell`. Now, The thing I want.

I have 2 storage accounts that both live in the same subscription.

- Storage1
- Storage2

Each storage have 1 container.

- Storage1 -> data1(container)
- Storage2 -> data2(container)

Now, `data1` contains the folder called `test` . And I want to copy this `test` folder in `data2` container.

in that `Azure CLI` `PowerShell` this is what I do:

```
.\AzCopy.exe /Source:"https://storage1.blob.core.windows.net/data1" /Dest:"https://storage2.blob.core.windows.net/data2" /SourceKey:"storage1keyhere" /DestKey:"storage2keyhere" /Pattern:"*"
```

This just tells me that no file was copied at all in the release logs. Why doesn't it copy anything at all? I also tried to use `/S` instead of `/Pattern:"*"` , but in that case, it's just hangs, no logs and nothing for about 20 minutes and I got tired of waiting.

How do I make this work? Agent is `Hosted VS2017`.

Answer (score 0):

Following [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs#copy-blobs-between-storage-accounts) I would give a goo for `--recursive`

```bsh
azcopy copy 'https://<source-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>/<directory-path><SAS-token>' 'https://<destination-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>' --recursive
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but There's no azcopy. Until I start writing .\AzCopy.exe, it always is an error.